# Trying Mqtt connection on Android using Paho MqttClient

Tags: android, connection, mqtt, paho

When you first open the app I want a screen where you can enter the broker information and click try and save.

When clicking try it should just show a `Snackbar` saying if the information makes for a successful connection.

This is the code I call when the try button is pressed:

```
private void tryConnection(View v){
    if(verifyInputs()){
        Snackbar.make(v, getString(R.string.trying_connection), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        String clientId = MqttClient.generateClientId();
        MqttAndroidClient client =
                new MqttAndroidClient(this.getApplicationContext(), getServerAddress(),
                        clientId);

        try {
            IMqttToken token = client.connect();
            final View vinner = v;
            token.setActionCallback(new IMqttActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(IMqttToken asyncActionToken) {
                    // We are connected
                    Snackbar.make(vinner, "Success", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(IMqttToken asyncActionToken, Throwable exception) {
                    // Something went wrong e.g. connection timeout or firewall problems
                    Snackbar.make(vinner, "Fail", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
        } catch (MqttException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is, `onFailure` doesn't seem to be called when it cannot connect to the server, but when a connection to a server is lost.

How do I just test the connection, so I can store it and go back to the main activity?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so I can't see your full service, any other implementation or how/where you are using this so I'm providing a sample of my MQTT service.

Maybe you can compare it, find any issue and fix it.

Or you can just use my implementation.  Up to you. Hope it helps.

```
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Binder;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.util.Log;

import org.eclipse.paho.android.service.MqttAndroidClient;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.IMqttActionListener;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.IMqttDeliveryToken;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.IMqttToken;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttCallback;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttConnectOptions;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttException;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttMessage;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttSecurityException;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.persist.MemoryPersistence;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MyMqttService extends Service implements MqttCallback, IMqttActionListener {

    private final IBinder binder = new MyBinder();

    private MqttAndroidClient mqttClient;
    private MqttConnectOptions mqttConnectOptions;
    private static final MemoryPersistence persistence = new MemoryPersistence();
    private ArrayList<MqttAndroidClient> lostConnectionClients;

    private String clientId = "";
    private boolean isReady = false;
    private boolean doConnectTask = true;
    private boolean isConnectInvoked = false;

    private Handler handler = new Handler();
    private final int RECONNECT_INTERVAL = 10000; // 10 seconds
    private final int DISCONNECT_INTERVAL = 20000; // 20 seconds
    private final int CONNECTION_TIMEOUT = 60;
    private final int KEEP_ALIVE_INTERVAL = 200;

    private String broker_url = "my_broker";

    public MyMqttService() {}

    public class MyBinder extends Binder {
        public MyMqttService getService() {
            return MyMqttService.this;
        }
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return binder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        initMqttClient();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        disconnectClients();
        if (isConnectInvoked && mqttClient != null && mqttClient.isConnected()) {
            try {
                // unsubscribe here
                unsubscribe("¯\\_(ツ)_/¯");
                mqttClient.disconnect();
            } catch (MqttException e) {
                Log.e("TAG", e.toString());
            }
        }

        handler.removeCallbacks(connect);
        handler.removeCallbacks(disconnect);
    }

    private void initMqttClient() {
        if(mqttClient != null) {
            mqttClient = null;
        }

        lostConnectionClients = new ArrayList<>();

        mqttConnectOptions = new MqttConnectOptions();
        mqttConnectOptions.setCleanSession(true);
        mqttConnectOptions.setConnectionTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
        mqttConnectOptions.setKeepAliveInterval(KEEP_ALIVE_INTERVAL);

        setNewMqttClient();

        handler.post(connect);
        handler.postDelayed(disconnect, DISCONNECT_INTERVAL);
    }

    private void setNewMqttClient() {
        mqttClient = new MqttAndroidClient(MyMqttService.this, broker_url, clientId, persistence);
        mqttClient.setCallback(this);
    }

    public Runnable connect = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            connectClient();
            handler.postDelayed(connect, RECONNECT_INTERVAL);
        }
    };

    public Runnable disconnect = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            disconnectClients();
            handler.postDelayed(disconnect, DISCONNECT_INTERVAL);
        }
    };

    private void connectClient() {
        if(doConnectTask) {
            doConnectTask = false;

            try {
                isConnectInvoked = true;
                mqttClient.connect(mqttConnectOptions, null, this);
            } catch (MqttException ex) {
                doConnectTask = true;
                Log.e("TAG", ex.toString());
            }
        }
    }

    private void disconnectClients() {
        if (lostConnectionClients.size() > 0) {
            // Disconnect lost connection clients
            for (MqttAndroidClient client : lostConnectionClients) {
                if (client.isConnected()) {
                    try {
                        client.disconnect();
                    } catch (MqttException e) {
                        Log.e("TAG", e.toString());
                    }
                }
            }

            // Close already disconnected clients
            for (int i = lostConnectionClients.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                try {
                    if (!lostConnectionClients.get(i).isConnected()) {
                        MqttAndroidClient client = lostConnectionClients.get(i);
                        client.close();
                        lostConnectionClients.remove(i);
                    }
                } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                    Log.e("TAG", e.toString());
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void deliveryComplete(IMqttDeliveryToken token) {
        Log.e("TAG", "deliveryComplete()");
    }

    @Override
    public void messageArrived(String topic, MqttMessage message) throws Exception {
        String payload = new String(message.getPayload());
        // do something
    }

    @Override
    public void connectionLost(Throwable cause) {
        Log.e("TAG", cause.getMessage());
    }

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(IMqttToken iMqttToken) {
        isReady = true;

        // subscribe here
         subscribe("¯\\_(ツ)_/¯");
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(IMqttToken iMqttToken, Throwable throwable) {
        setNewMqttClient();
        isReady = false;
        doConnectTask = true;
        isConnectInvoked = false;
    }

    private void subscribe(String topic) {
        try {
            mqttClient.subscribe(topic, 0);
            isReady = true;
        } catch (MqttSecurityException mqttSexEx) {
            isReady = false;
        } catch (MqttException mqttEx) {
            isReady = false;
        }
    }

    private void unsubscribe(String topic) {
        try {
            mqttClient.unsubscribe(topic);
        } catch (MqttSecurityException mqttSecEx) {
            Log.e("TAG", mqttSecEx.getMessage());
        } catch (MqttException mqttEx) {
            Log.e("TAG", mqttEx.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private void publish(String topic, String jsonPayload) {
        if(!isReady) {
            return;
        }

        try {
            MqttMessage msg = new MqttMessage();
            msg.setQos(0);
            msg.setPayload(jsonPayload.getBytes("UTF-8"));
            mqttClient.publish(topic, msg);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.e("TAG", ex.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

My other suggestion would be to just setup local broadcast so when your activity loads and you start the service, if MQTT service is able to connect, you send a broadcast saying connected and you show a `Snackbar`. If connection failed, you send a different broadcast and show a different message.

Comment: hi ! Im using your service, or at least trying to. Can you please explain me how can I make a subscribe ? I am completely lost, have been on this for hours

Comment: @NelsonSilva there is a `onSuccess` callback for MQTT. Once the connection to broker is successful, that method will be called. So all you have to do is call the `subscribe` method there and pass in the `topic` you are subscribing to as a parameter. Are you getting any errors or any specific issues?

Comment: Actually I've tried so many things that I dont know where to start. I've been watching videos on youtube, using the "ServiceConnection" and binding the service but I cant get to nowhere. when I try to subscribe, I get a >org.eclipse.paho.android.service.MqttAndroidClient.subscribe(java.lang.String, int)' on a null object reference. Also, to make the subscribe I need a IMqttToken ? Im so lost, sorry...I dont understand the proper way to call the method from inside the service

Comment: @NelsonSilva I can't determine the issue without seeing your implementation. Please start a new question and show your `Service` code so we can see what's wrong

Comment: @THEPATEL I'm using your code, that's all I have... I've been dropping everything else since it doesn't work. If you could provide me a simple code snippet showing how to subscribe, I would be very grateful

Comment: I think the service has a lot going on and it might be hard to find where the issue is. For now, I would not start the `Service` and implement these few lines of code in you `Activity` to test. Just make sure to change the broker URL from `tcp://localhost:1883` to your broker URL. The important thing here is to test what prints in the logs. https://stackoverflow.com/a/43038678/3866010

Comment: @THEPATEL I tried the call back method and It worked, thank you, but I still have the issue the I thought would be solved with the Service runing on brackground. If you could please take a look, this is my issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47992062/keep-mqtt-topics-subscribed-onresume-activity