# Android Studio - MQTT not connecting

Tags: android, android-studio, mqtt, iot, mosquitto

I have just started learning using MQTT protocol with Android Studio. Using **mosquitto** broker, I am able to exchange messages between **pub/sub** windows. But when I send message to broker through android studio, the app builds successfully but nothing displays on broker's end & system prints Connection Failure. The same code works fine on eclipse java application, but not working on android although required libraries and dependencies have been added.

Please help, what am I missing in this basic step so i can learn forward. Thank you!

**app-build.gradle**

```
    dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

// have added following dependencies

    provided 'com.google.android.things:androidthings:0.2-devpreview'
    provided 'com.google.android.things:androidthings:0.1-devpreview'
    compile 'org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3:1.0.2'

}
```

**project-build.gradle**

```
   repositories {
            jcenter()
            maven {
                url "https://repo.eclipse.org/content/repositories/paho-snapshots/"
            }    
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.zoha.mqttandroidiot">

    <!-- Permissions the Application Requires -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">


        <activity android:name=".HomeActivity">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>

            <!-- Launch activity automatically on boot -->
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.IOT_LAUNCHER"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
<service android:name="org.eclipse.paho.android.service.MqttService"/>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

**HomeActivity**

```
  public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    MqttAndroidClient client;
   // private static final MemoryPersistence persistence = new MemoryPersistence();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final MqttAndroidClient mqttAndroidClient = new MqttAndroidClient(this.getApplicationContext(), "tcp://localhost:1883", "androidSampleClient");
        mqttAndroidClient.setCallback(new MqttCallback() {
            @Override
            public void connectionLost(Throwable cause) {
                System.out.println("Connection was lost!");

            }

            @Override
            public void messageArrived(String topic, MqttMessage message) throws Exception {
                System.out.println("Message Arrived!: " + topic + ": " + new String(message.getPayload()));

            }

            @Override
            public void deliveryComplete(IMqttDeliveryToken token) {
                System.out.println("Delivery Complete!");
            }
        });

        try {
            mqttAndroidClient.connect(null, new IMqttActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(IMqttToken asyncActionToken) {
                    System.out.println("Connection Success!");
                    try {
                        System.out.println("Subscribing to /test");
                        mqttAndroidClient.subscribe("/test", 0);
                        System.out.println("Subscribed to /test");
                        System.out.println("Publishing message..");
                        mqttAndroidClient.publish("/test", new MqttMessage("Hello world testing..!".getBytes()));
                    } catch (MqttException ex) {

                    }

                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(IMqttToken asyncActionToken, Throwable exception) {
                    System.out.println("Connection Failure!");
                }
            });
        } catch (MqttException ex) {

        }


    }
    }
```

Comment: Also, make sure to fix the `service` tags in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file. `service..` tag should be outside your `activity` tag. So copy the `‹service..` line and paste it below the `</activity>` line

Comment: Change the BROKER url to your system ip address not your mobile's ip.

Answer (score 4):

I wanted to just add a comment, but my rep is too low...so i'm posting it as an answer.

You said you got everything working but are unable to connect because of the `IllegalArgumentException`. I had the same problem and found out that you need to define the protocol also.
So instead of `"192.168.0.103:1883"` try:

`String serverURI = "tcp://192.168.0.103:1883"`

From what i read you already did the other necessary steps, but for the sake of giving a complete answer:

1. Edit the `AndroidManifest.xml` to include:

   - `<service android:name="org.eclipse.paho.android.service.MqttService" />`
     (from inside the `application` tag)
   - `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`
   - `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />`
   - `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />`
   - `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />`
2. Edit the `build.gradle` to include (in the `dependencies` section):

   - `compile 'org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3:1.1.1'`
   - `compile 'org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.android.service:1.1.1'`
3. Use the `MqttAndroidClient` (not the `MqttClient`)
4. Put your code in the "onSuccess" callback, to avoid any problems due to the methods being asynchronous (as shown by THEPATEL's answer):

   ```
   MqttConnectOptions mqttConnectOptions = new MqttConnectOptions();
   mqttConnectOptions.setKeepAliveInterval(60);//seconds
   mqttConnectOptions.setCleanSession(true);
   mqttConnectOptions.setAutomaticReconnect(true);

   mqttAndroidClient.connect(mqttConnectOptions, null, new IMqttActionListener() {
           @Override
           public void onSuccess(IMqttToken asyncActionToken) {
               //Treat success here (subscribe, publish etc)
           }

           @Override
           public void onFailure(IMqttToken asyncActionToken, Throwable exception) {
               //Treat failure here
           }
       });
   ```

Answer (score 3):

Ok so you need two libraries to use MQTT in Android. One is the mqtt paho client and other being Android service library.

```
compile 'org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.android.service:1.0.2'
compile 'org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3:1.0.2'
```

Then, use `MqttAndroidClient` instead of `MqttClient`.

So do `new MqttAndroidClient(...)`.

I posted a full Android MQTT service example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42189627/trying-mqtt-connection-on-android-using-paho-mqttclient/42191432#42191432), if that helps.

> **EDIT: full activity example**

(1) `MemoryPersistence` added when creating new `MqttAndroidClient`.
(2) Two parameters added to `.connect()` method of the `MqttAndroidClient` (`mqttConnectOptions` and `null`).
(3) Also, printing the error on `onFailure()`

```
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private MqttAndroidClient client;
    private final MemoryPersistence persistence = new MemoryPersistence();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final MqttAndroidClient mqttAndroidClient = new MqttAndroidClient(this.getApplicationContext(), "tcp://localhost:1883", "androidSampleClient", persistence);
        mqttAndroidClient.setCallback(new MqttCallback() {
            @Override
            public void connectionLost(Throwable cause) {
                System.out.println("Connection was lost!");
            }

            @Override
            public void messageArrived(String topic, MqttMessage message) throws Exception {
                System.out.println("Message Arrived!: " + topic + ": " + new String(message.getPayload()));
            }

            @Override
            public void deliveryComplete(IMqttDeliveryToken token) {
                System.out.println("Delivery Complete!");
            }
        });

        MqttConnectOptions mqttConnectOptions = new MqttConnectOptions();
        mqttConnectOptions.setCleanSession(true);

        try {
            mqttAndroidClient.connect(mqttConnectOptions, null, new IMqttActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(IMqttToken asyncActionToken) {
                    System.out.println("Connection Success!");
                    try {
                        System.out.println("Subscribing to /test");
                        mqttAndroidClient.subscribe("/test", 0);
                        System.out.println("Subscribed to /test");
                        System.out.println("Publishing message..");
                        mqttAndroidClient.publish("/test", new MqttMessage("Hello world testing..!".getBytes()));
                    } catch (MqttException ex) {

                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(IMqttToken asyncActionToken, Throwable exception) {
                    System.out.println("Connection Failure!");
                    System.out.println("throwable: " + exception.toString());
                }
            });
        } catch (MqttException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. But now its giving null pointer exception on publish statement: 'org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.IMqttDeliveryToken org.eclipse.paho.android.service.MqttService.publish(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttMessage, java.lang.String, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

Comment: @Noor can you debug and find out which one of the parameter is null? If anything, just try to print each parameter in log and see which one is null. I seems like a very simple issue

Comment: @th3pat3I Can you please see the revised code? It's now giving no error & but says Connection Failure.

Comment: @Noor i posted a sample. give it a try

Comment: @th3pat3I Thank you so much for your quick response. With your sample,  connection fails with the message:

unable to connect to server (32103) - java.net.connectException: failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1(port 1883) after 3000ms: isConnected failed: ECONNREFUSED (connection refused) ). 

I also tried "192.168.0.103:1883" as broker address which is my pc's ip address then it gives java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 192.168.0.103:1883.

 Still trying to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with MQTT publisher from an android device. While referring to `tcp://localhost:1883` from an android emulator, I had to use `http://10.0.2.2:1883` since emulator runs on its own VM and localhost would be emulators own loopback address.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting Same Error but I have solved it.
This is working code.

in gradle :

```
compile 'org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3:1.1.0'
    compile 'org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.android.service:1.1.0'
```

In Manifest :

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

Service Tag inside Application:

```
  <service android:name="org.eclipse.paho.android.service.MqttService" >
        </service>
```

Activity Code :

```
 MqttAndroidClient client;
 Button btnsub,btnpublish;
```

to connect with Mqtt client:

```
String clientId = MqttClient.generateClientId();
   client = new MqttAndroidClient(getApplicationContext(), "tcp://www.domain.in/ip:11883",clientId);
        client.connect().setActionCallback(new IMqttActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(IMqttToken asyncActionToken) {
                // We are connected
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(IMqttToken asyncActionToken, Throwable exception) {
            }
        });
```

To SubScribe on button click :

```
   client.subscribe("topic", 0, null, new IMqttActionListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(IMqttToken asyncActionToken) {
                        }
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(IMqttToken asyncActionToken, Throwable exception) {
                        }
                    });
                    client.subscribe("topic", 0, new IMqttMessageListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void messageArrived(String topic, MqttMessage message) throws Exception {
                        }
                    });
```

to Publish on button click :

```
   MqttMessage message = new MqttMessage();
                    message.setPayload("message".getBytes());
                    client.publish("topic", message);
```