# Android - MQTT and Mosquitto

Tags: java, android, mqtt, mosquitto, paho

I'm working in a project that trying to publish and subscribe to the MQTTHOST test.mosquitto.org:1833
But when I run my code, always occurrs "you app keeps stopping".

I used the same code from the youtube video, (Paho): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BAkGm02WBc0

My code:

MainActivity

```
package com.carlospacheco.mce_app_ifsp;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.eclipse.paho.android.service.MqttAndroidClient;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.IMqttActionListener;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.IMqttToken;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttClient;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttConnectOptions;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttException;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    static String MQTTHOST  = "test.mosquitto.org:1883";
    static String USERNAME  = "";
    static String PASSWORD  = "";
    String topicStr = "LED";

    MqttAndroidClient client;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        String clientId = MqttClient.generateClientId();
        client = new MqttAndroidClient(this.getApplicationContext(), MQTTHOST, clientId);

        MqttConnectOptions options = new MqttConnectOptions();
        options.setUserName(USERNAME);
        options.setPassword(PASSWORD.toCharArray());


        try {
            IMqttToken token = client.connect(options);
            token.setActionCallback(new IMqttActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(IMqttToken asyncActionToken) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Conectado!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(IMqttToken asyncActionToken, Throwable exception) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Conexão Falhou!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
        } catch (MqttException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void pub(View v){
        String topic = topicStr;
        String message = "hello world from ifi gaming";
        try {
            client.publish(topic, message.getBytes(),0, false);
        } catch (MqttException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.carlospacheco.mce_app_ifsp"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
repositories {
    maven {
        url "https://repo.eclipse.org/content/repositories/paho-releases/"
    }
}
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.localbroadcastmanager:localbroadcastmanager:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    compile('org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.android.service:1.0.2') {
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }
}
```

activity main

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Conectar"
        android:onClick="pub"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="45dp" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image: The message error in the app]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50109744/6750327

Comment: Please do not post images of text, they are really hard to read and impossible for people who use screen readers. You need to make sure the error is printed to the logs, then include the text of the logs formatted properly in the question. As it is we can not see enough context of this to be able to help properly as we need to see more of the `IlegalArgumentException`

Answer (score 1):

As I said in the comments, without the full exception stack trace this question is impossible to answer properly but I'll take a guess

The value of MQTTHOST is supposed to be a full [URI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier) pointing at the MQTT broker. At the moment you have `test.mosquitto.org:1883` which is not a full URI.

A full URI needs to include a protocol before the host section.

In this case you need to add either `tcp://` or `mqtt://` before the host and port components.

```
static String MQTTHOST = "tcp://test.mosquitto.org:1883";
```